# Is there a cross browser way to turn off cookies using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-browser

Everyone of us knows the new law which is a pain for developers who are using cookies on their websites.

We have to ask our users if they allow us to create cookies on their machines. If they won't allow us this thing, how do we turn off cookies with javascript?

Is there a way to turn off cookies just for one website? Is there a compatible script which will work for all browsers?

What about 3rd parties cookies (Youtube, or Google Analytics? They are also stored in our website folder..)

Thank you!

Comment: If this is really a new rule I think it would be implemented at the browser level. It would be out of the hands of the programmer.

Comment: "*We have to ask our users if they allow us to create cookies on their machines.*" -- Okay, ask them, and if they agree, create your cookies. If they refuse, delete your existing cookies and don't store any others. If this is not sufficient, why not? Could you cite the law in question?

Comment: I wasn't able to turn up a direct link to the legislation, but a search for 'EU Cookie Directive' turns up plenty of articles such as this one: http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't turn off cookies from the client.  Your client code can stop creating new cookies, but even then the server could still be putting cookies on the page.  If you want to stop creating cookies for a particular site, then you need to stop doing so in both your client code and your server code.

FYI, is it really cookies-per-se that are the problem - or is it more what you do with those cookies (like tracking a given user).  For example, if you set a cookie just to remember what tab the current user was last on (with no other identifying information in the cookie and no use of that cookie on the server), is that a problem?  Or, a cookie that stores a temporary session ID so that the server can keep track of the items in your shopping cart.   I doubt these are issues because these aren't tracking or privacy issues.

As every country has their own laws in regard to this, if you are aiming for compliance with a particular country's laws, you will have to consult their exact laws.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what all the different laws are across different countries, but the Dutch cookielaws aren't all that strict and most sites won't have to change a thing. You might want to look into the exact laws that apply to your website before you try to purge all cookie creations from it.

In short [Dutch cookielaws](http://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/ict/veilig-online-en-e-privacy/internetbezoek-volgen-met-cookies) come down to:

- A website must **ask permission** to place cookies that **track** the user (this includes 3rd party cookies, such as cookies added by Google).
- A website doesn't need to ask users for permission to place cookies that are required to run the website. An example of such a cookie is a cookie that keeps track of what you placed in your shopping cart.

Most implementations of this law that I have seen so far are similar to the one found on [fok.nl](http://fok.nl/). The first time the user opens the site a large popup is thrown into their face that will only let the user open the real website if they permit the site to place cookies. I assume this setting is then stored in a new cookie so the user never gets bothered with it again. This solution shouldn't be too difficult to implement.

**Edit:**

Here are some more examples of implementations: http://www.stormmc.nl/nieuws/nederlandse-voorbeelden-implementatie-cookiewet/ (just click the links).